# Does live Change still not work in IE 8 with jquery 1.4.2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.4

I heard this issue is fixed in jquery 1.4.2 but I am still getting this problem. I am using

```
"~/Plugins/jquery-1.4.2.js"
```

I have this

```
$('#id').live('change', function (e)
{
  // do stuff
});
```

It works in firefox 3.6 but not ie 8.

Comment: suprising,it is working for me

Comment: Is `"~/Plugins/jquery-1.4.2.js"` what you are writing in your script tag to include the js file?

Comment: naw that is in some xml(used to combine all js files together) file and that is just how the path is written. I am pretty sure it is the right path otherwise my site would not work(take away jquery and my site does not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change event works perfectly for me in all browsers including IE6+.

Check out the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EsVR3/ .

What element are you using the 'change' event on?

Marko

Comment: Ya I see it works on your even when I change to dropdown list. It's so weird not sure why it does not work. Like I said it works in firefox no problem. I changed it to live query and that works as well.

Comment: So my one works for you but you can't get it to work on your webpage? Have you wrapped your code inside the $(document).ready() event?

Comment: Yep. I have it in a document.ready() like I said works in all browsers except IE 8. I tried a localhost of jquery and hosted on google does not still work. I wrapped my event with the jquery livequery plugin and it works in IE8 and all browsers.

Comment: Yes your works just fine and I tried changing it to drop down list and it works too. Like I said I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Hmm that's odd - if you like you can post your code on jsFiddle or pastebin and I can have a look for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `delegate` function instead of `live` it will solve the problem. For example:

```
$('body').delegate("#selectpage","change", function() {
      alert("Changed!");
});
```